# If metabox is empty display other content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, iframe

I'm trying to replace or show other content if the metabox is empty but I can't make it work, here is what I have done.

If "ytvideourl" is empty display "ytembed" iframe content

```
<div class="trailer"><iframe src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ytvideourl', true);?>

<?php if( ! empty( $ytvideourl ) ) : ?>

 <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ytembed', true);?>?rel=0">

<?php endif; ?> ?rel=0"></iframe></div>
```

Real current code:

```
<div class="trailer">
    <?php
    $ytvideourl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ytvideourl', true);
?>
    
    <?php if( ! empty( $ytvideourl ) ) : ?>
    <iframe src="<?php echo $ytvideourl; ?>"></iframe>
    <?php else : ?>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ytembed', true);?>?rel=0?" width="400" height="230" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" data-mce-type="bookmark" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" data-mce-type="bookmark" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" data-mce-type="bookmark" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" data-mce-type="bookmark" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span></iframe>  
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to store the meta value to a variable. Then check whether that variable is empty or not. If not empty, then use that value. Otherwise if it's empty, then fetch the second meta value and use it.

Here's the example:

```
<?php
    $ytvideourl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ytvideourl', true);
    if( $ytvideourl !== false ) $ytvideourl = trim( $ytvideourl ); //-- remove any white spaces
?>
<div class="trailer">
    <?php if( ! empty( $ytvideourl ) ) : ?>
        <iframe src="<?php echo $ytvideourl; ?>"></iframe>
    <?php else : ?>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ytembed', true);?>?rel=0"></iframe>  
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh, it seems to work but doesn't show the conditional iframe if ytvideourl is empty just show an empty box.

I have updated the code above, I have included the current code, I did not place it so that my question would be cleaner.

Comment: The result is <iframe src=" "></iframe>

Comment: @EnmanuelGo Can you please try my updated code? My guess is that your `ytvideourl` might have some white spaces, even though you have not saved any url in it. Also, can you please confirm whether you have store any values in `ytvideourl` and `ytembed` meta fields ?

Comment: Now is working, what I try to save in ytvideourl is an embed url of my site, your first line of updated code worked, it seemed that there was some blank space although I really did not notice it.

Thank you very much, very grateful.

Comment: @EnmanuelGo glad to know that you got it resolved! :)